# Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument when using -runAs

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run a powershell script which will have run only after passing a parameter value as an argument. The script has few commands that run only with elevated access so trying to use -runAs verb like below:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~reset-password-services_logs.ps1 'h5rU!J5L_sitL0Y'""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

I need to pass the argument 'h5rU!J5L_sitL0Y' with the script in order to successfully execute the process. Error i get is below:

```
    Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'h5rU!J5L_sitL0Y'.
At line:1 char:4
+ & {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypas ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Are you running the command from a [tag:batch-file]? If not, please remove that tag…

Comment: I am not understanding why you would execute Powershell that executes another instance of Powershell that finally executes your powershell script.

Comment: The requirement is to run reset-password-services_logs.ps1 by passing 'h5rU!J5L_sitL0Y' as an argument and there are commands inside the script that would require elevated access. What is the best way to do it?